# Use awk command to output of ls command

Tags: linux, bash, script, awk, ls

I have a e-book directory that has following format:

```
<authorname> <authorsurname> - <bookname>
```

I want to separate the books by authors. I use the below command in a for-loop for this operation:

```
for author in $(ls /home/me/books | awk -F "-" '{print $1}' | sort | uniq)
do
    make a directory and push all books of this author to this directory 
done
```

I expect to see *authorsurname* value on next of *authorname* value but these values getting printed line by line. If I run the ls command that in the for-loop as individual this time it runs as I want (output 1). But in a loop, it doesn't (output 2).

Visually Output:

What I want:

```
Edgar Allan Poe
Marcus Aurelius
```

What happens:

```
Edgar
Allan
Poe
Marcus
Aurelius
```

How can I fix this issue and sort the authors as name and surname in same line?

Edit: I tried "cat" a file that contains author names. But it didn't work too.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expanded value of `$(command)` is a single flat string containing all lines of the command's output. It is not a multi-element array of individual lines.

All unquoted shell expansions, whether `$variables` or `$(commands)`, are subject to [word splitting.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) As the name implies, by default the value is split into individual words – *not lines* – based on the separators found in $IFS.

To loop over each line, either use `mapfile` to import input into an *actual* array variable (with each line as a separate array element, as can be seen in `declare -p authors` later)...

```
mapfile -t authors < <(ls | awk)

for author in "${authors[@]}"; do
    ...
done

# Note that the < and the <() are two independent operators.
# < <() is used instead of ls|awk|mapfile because pipeline elements
# run in their own scope and cannot alter "parent" variables.
```

...or replace `for` with a pipeline and a 'read' loop...

```
ls | awk | while read -r author; do
    ...
done

# In this case, using a pipeline is okay as long as the 'while' loop
# doesn't need to make variable modifications that remain after the loop.
```

...or skip the whole thing entirely and just use wildcard expansion:

```
for book in /home/me/books/*; do
    filename=${book##*/}
    author=${filename%% - *}
    make a $author directory if needed, then move this one book to that directory
done

# Expansions within the right-hand side of a variable assignment
# are actually exempt from word splitting, so they can remain unquoted.
```